I am trying to show my android app reviews on my website but return 401 when Authenticated
I am trying to show my android app reviews with reviewer name, date, rating. But I have some problems with authentication. Using google cloud with OAuth 2.0 Client IDs.
I use google/apiclient with PHP composer
{
"name": "app/reviews",
"description": "A project to fetch Google Play Store reviews using PHP",
"require": {
    "google/apiclient": "^2.15.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}

here's
credentials.json
{
   "web":{
      "client_id":"******-********.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "project_id":"****-****-373117",
      "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_secret":"GOCSPX-*******"
   }
}

here's PHP code to show reviews
<?php
require '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\AndroidPublisher;

function getReviews($applicationName) {
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Reviews Client');
    $client->setAuthConfig('/path/to/credentials.json');
    $client->addScope(AndroidPublisher::ANDROIDPUBLISHER);
    
    $service = new AndroidPublisher($client);
    
    try {
        $reviews = $service->reviews->listReviews($applicationName);
        return $reviews;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: ', $e->getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}

$applicationName = 'com.****.****';
$reviews = getReviews($applicationName);

if ($reviews) {
    foreach ($reviews as $review) {
        echo 'Rating: ' . $review->getStars() . '<br>';
        echo 'Comment: ' . $review->getText() . '<br><br>';
    }
}
?>

but I get this when run it!
I want to know what's the problem? Why Authentication failed.

